# JTable Calculator

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want this function to work. This function is called by the game loop to get the selected rows in the table. I dont understand why the error message of:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]
    - Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after this 
     token

Wondering if anyone could explain what it is that I need to change to make my function getRows work. Thanks for your time and hope to hear back soon.

```
    public int[] getRows(JTable table) {    
    rows[0] = table.getSelectedRow();
    rowCount = table.getSelectedRowCount() - 1;
    rows[1] = rows[0] + rowCount;
    return rows[];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is simple, the explanation isn't.

What you did wrong: `return rows[];`. It should be `return rows;`.

The explanation:

When you want to return an array you should not add the brackets. If you would want to return one item of an array you should write `return array[index];`. What the compiler thinks in your case is that you are trying to return one int from the array `rows` but forgot the index, that's a syntax error. The type mismatch is because you said you would return an `int[]` (and the compiler thought you are trying to return an `int`, remember?) in the method header.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] getRows(JTable table) {    
    rows[0] = table.getSelectedRow();
    rowCount = table.getSelectedRowCount() - 1;
    rows[1] = rows[0] + rowCount;
    return rows; //////////without brackets
}
```